# websphere 8.5.5 admin console changes

Tags: console, websphere-8

We have an application deployed in websphere 8.5.5. We want to verify the session management settings, if we modify session management settings like cookie config settings and save the changes, where exactly the changes are stored?
Is it stored in web sphere's file or in the web.xml of the deployed application?

Answer (score 0):

1. If a change is made at JVM level, *Application servers > SERVER_NAME > Session management*, then the server.xml for the JVM is updated *PROFILE_NAME/cells / CELL_NAME /nodes/ NODE_NAME /servers / JVM_NAME /server.xml*
2. If change is made at application level,
   *Enterprise Applications > NAME_OF_APPLICATION > Session management*
   then deployment.xml will show the changes
   *PROFILE_NAME/cells/ CELL_NAME /applications/ APPLICATION_NAME /deployments/ APPLICATION_NAME / deployment.xml*

Answer (score 0):

You can always instead of `Save` click `Review` and then expand changed files. You will have list of changed xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the next step by step

1. Web admin Console

> Application servers > server1 > Session management > Save

Save your workspace changes to the master configuration.

Click Save to update the master repository with your changes. Click Discard to discard your changes and begin work again using the master repository configuration. Click Cancel to continue working with your changes.

Expand or collapse Total changed documents: 1

Changed Items   Status

```
cells / server1Cell01 / nodes / server1TPNode05 / servers / server1/ server.xml Updated
```

Synchronize changes with Nodes

2. Server file

   /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/config/cells/Server1Cell01/nodes/server1TPNode05/servers/server1/server.xml:

Thanks and regards

tandn

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to clarify what you mean? As it stands, it's rather difficult to read and unclear whether this is an answer, or a question (due to the "please help"). See [answer] for guidelines.